# Expected one matching request for criteria

Tags: javascript, angular, unit-testing

I am trying to follow the angular guide to testing services using the new HTTP Client. I am getting the following error, `Expected one matching request for criteria "Match method: GET, URL: http://localhost:8080/services/shift/2016-12-01", found none.` I have put my code below, not too sure where I'm going wrong

**Unit Test**

```
import { HttpTestingController, HttpClientTestingModule } from '@angular/common/http/testing';
import { HttpClient, HttpHandler } from '@angular/common/http';
import { TestBed } from '@angular/core/testing';

import { ShiftService } from './shift.service';

let service: ShiftService;
let backend: HttpTestingController;

describe('ShiftService', () => {
  beforeEach(() => {
    TestBed.configureTestingModule({
      providers: [
        ShiftService,
        HttpClient,
        HttpHandler
      ],
      imports: [HttpClientTestingModule]
    });

    service = TestBed.get(ShiftService);
    backend = TestBed.get(HttpTestingController);
  });

  afterEach(() => {
    backend.verify();
  });

  describe('When the getShift method is invoked', () => {
    it('should make a GET request to the services/shift endpoint', async() => {
      service.getShift().subscribe();
      backend.expectOne({
        url: 'http://localhost:8080/services/shift/2016-12-01',
        method: 'GET'
      });
    });
  });
});
```

**Service**

```
import { HttpClient } from '@angular/common/http';
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';

@Injectable({
  providedIn: 'root'
})

export class ShiftService {
  constructor(private http: HttpClient) { }

  public getShift = () => {
    return this.http.get('http://localhost:8080/services/shift/2016-12-01');
  }
}
```

I have made sure to subscribe to my getShift() method and I am using the HTTPTestingController. I have also tried the other overloads of the HttpTestingController and no luck :/ Thank you for any help in advance!

Comment: facing the same issue. Please update if you find a solution

Comment: I solved my issue, I was just adding a slash at the end of the url, after removing the slash, it worked. hope it helps !

Answer (score 0):

```
  use describe as below

 describe('When the getShift method is invoked', () => {
    it('should make a GET request to the services/shift endpoint', async() => {
        const path = '/testPath';
        service.get(path).subscribe(response => {
            expect(response).toBeTruthy();
        });

        const httpRequest = httpMock.expectOne(
        (req: HttpRequest<any>) => req.urlWithParams === path); 

     // write your expect criteria here....
      });
  });
```